# Add a custom dynamic text after the product variation selected price in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, price

I am new to woocommerce and I'm try for a week to display below a variable price a proposal for a payment in 4x.

I tried several techniques and code found on the net but none with good results.

The best I could do and this:

```html
//Afficher paiement 3xcb//


add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 'display_3xcb', 99, 4);

function display_3xcb($html, $price, $product) {
 global $post, $product;
 $variation_id = '7575';
 $cb_price = get_post_meta($variation_id, '_sale_price', true);
 $cb_price = ($cb_price/4);
 $html = '<p> Ou simplement en 4 x ' . $cb_price . '€ sans frais</p>'; 
 return $html;
}
```

But my problem is that my `$variation_id` is not dynamic.

Do you have an idea of how to it retrieves the id of the Selected variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For product variations addition suffix to the selected price use instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_variation_price_addition', 10, 3 );
function custom_variation_price_addition( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    $price  = wc_get_price_to_display( $variation );
    $suffix = sprintf( __("Ou simplement en 4 x %s sans frais"), wc_price($price / 4) );

    $data['price_html'] .= '<span class="4xcb"> ' . $suffix . '</span>';

    return $data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
function the_product_price() {
    global $product;
    global $woocommerce;
    $regular_price = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);
    if ($regular_price == "") {
        $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        if ($available_variations) {
            $variation_id = $available_variations[0]['variation_id'];  
            $variable_product1 = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);
            $regular_price = $variable_product1->regular_price;
        }
    }
    echo '<span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">'.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().' </span>'.$regular_price.'</span></span>';

}
```

Above function get the regular price for particular sequential price of product.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but always display the same price. No change in case of size change.